# Loading different images from cache using Glide Library

Tags: android, mysql, image, caching, android-glide

i am retrieving images URL using volley from MySQL Database , when am online i have no problem , but i need to make it offline too so am using SQLite to store data, but when the image loads it displays the first picture saved in cache , and i have no idea how to resolve this.

I was using BLOB before but the application became too slow after adding lot of data.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use signature

```
   Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())) //use this 
        .into(imgView);
```

Comment: it doesn't display anything when i'am offline , i don't get it

Comment: actully it reloads the old image

Comment: you kept diskcache?

Comment: i have the same code up there , i just added signature() .

Comment: have you added diskcache startage ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141893/discussion-between-ous-sama-and-raut-darpan).

Comment: Helped me on **chat** , i **deleted** `signature()` and now its working _online_ and _offline_ , displaying the correct image , **thank you !**